# C segmentation fault using structures

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_SUB_COMMANDS 5
#define MAX_ARGS 10
struct SubCommand
{
char *line;
char *argv[MAX_ARGS];
};
struct Command
{
struct SubCommand sub_commands[MAX_SUB_COMMANDS];
int num_sub_commands;
};
void ReadCommand(char *line, struct Command **command);
void PrintCommand(struct Command **command);
void read_args(char *in, char *argv[MAX_ARGS], int size);
void print_args(char *argv[MAX_ARGS]);
int main()
{
    char s[200];
    printf("Enter Command:");
    fgets(s,200,stdin);
    s[strlen(s)-1]='\0';
    struct Command *command;
    ReadCommand(s,&command);
    PrintCommand(&command);
}
void ReadCommand(char *line, struct Command **command)
{
    const char *delim ="|";
    const char *k;
    char *copy;
    char *l;
    int i=0;
    (*command)->num_sub_commands=0;
    k=strtok(line,delim);
    while(k!=NULL)
    {
        l=strdup(k);
        (*command)->sub_commands[i].line=l;
        printf("(*command)->sub_commands[%d].line=%s,l=%s\n",i,(*command)->sub_commands[i].line,l);
        i++;
        printf("%d iteration\n",i);
        (*command)->num_sub_commands++;
        printf("%d number of subcommands\n",(*command)->num_sub_commands);
        k=strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
    (*command)->sub_commands[i].line=NULL;
    for(i=0;(*command)->sub_commands[i].line!=NULL;i++)
    {
        copy=strdup((*command)->sub_commands[i].line);
        read_args(copy,(*command)->sub_commands[i].argv,MAX_ARGS);
    }
}
void read_args(char *in, char *argv[MAX_ARGS], int size)
{
        const char *del =" ";
    int i=0;
        const char *k1;
        char *l1;
        k1=strtok(in,del);
            while(k1!=NULL)
            {
                l1=strdup(k1);
                argv[i]=l1;
                //printf("argv[%d]=%s\n",i,argv[i]);
                i++;
                //printf("k1=%s\n",k1);
                //printf("l1=%s\n",l1);
                k1=strtok(NULL,del);
            }
    argv[i]=NULL;
}
void PrintCommand(struct Command **command)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;(*command)->sub_commands[i].line!=NULL;i++)
    {
        printf("subcommand[%d]='%s' \n",i,(*command)->sub_commands[i].line);
        print_args((*command)->sub_commands[i].argv);
    }
}
void print_args(char *argv[MAX_ARGS])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;argv[i]!=NULL;i++)
    {
        printf("argv[%d]='%s' \n",i,argv[i]);
    }
}
```

i am getting segmentation fault, donno why? anyone can help??
i am getting the segmentation fault while runnig in the devc++ ide and when i am running my code on shell with optimization flag O0 it is working fine.

Comment: Empty lines and spaces are not only to sepearte tokens for the compiler. Format your code. Also strip it down to a [mcve].

Comment: "anyone can help?". Yes, you can help yourself by using your debugger to find exactly where the seg fault occurs.

Comment: I rectified my mistake thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in your code any malloc (and any free).

And in your main you can do:

```
struct Command command; //I don't understand why you are using pointers here
ReadCommand(s,command);
PrintCommand(command);
```

And you can change:

```
void ReadCommand(char *line, struct Command **command);
void PrintCommand(struct Command **command);
```

with:

```
void ReadCommand(char *line, struct Command *command);
void PrintCommand(struct Command *command);
```

And for example PrintCommand can be:

```
void PrintCommand(struct Command *command)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;command->sub_commands[i].line!=NULL;i++)
    {
        printf("subcommand[%d]='%s' \n",i,command->sub_commands[i].line);
        print_args(command->sub_commands[i].argv);
    }
}
```

Also remember to use `free` for `line` and `argv` of `SubCommand` struct, when you finish using them.